# Google cloud run liveness probe issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I configured a liveness grpc probe on my cloud run service and it is not working as I would expect. I added the following to my service yaml file:

```
livenessProbe:
           timeoutSeconds: 30
           periodSeconds: 30
           failureThreshold: 3
           grpc:
             port: [PORT]
```

I would expect this probe to hit my grpc health check endpoint every 30 seconds and shutdown after 3 failed requests. This works as expected for the most part, but I am seeing what seem to be bugs or unexpected failures of the liveness probe. For the first 3 days after I configured the probe, I saw logs like this:
`LIVENESS GRPC probe failed 1 time consecutively for container...`
which made me think that it wasn't actually using the correct failure threshold of 3. Now, I keep seeing logs like this:
`LIVENESS GRPC probe failed 0 time consecutively for container...`
which make me think the liveness probe isn't failing at ALL yet the container is still being shut down. I also have logs in my health checking code and the health check endpoint isn't being hit let alone failing. Seems like a network error or error from GCP somehow. Also seems like it could be related to autoscaling?

I have looked for docs on more details on how cloud run's liveness probe works but haven't encountered any fixes/internal details. Please help!

Tried adding a liveness probe and it fails unexpectedly when health check still passes.